# findfont: Generic family 'sans-serif' not found because none of the following families were found: Montserrat

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to use one of the Google fonts in my MatPlotLib project. It's called 'Montserrat' ([you can see it here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat))

My short example Python program is throwing the following message:

```
findfont: Generic family 'sans-serif' not found because none of the following families were found: Montserrat
```

**test.py**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.font_manager
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Montserrat']

x = [2001, 2002, 2003]
y = [2001, 2002, 2003]

index = x
width = 0.50

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects = plt.bar(index, y, width)

plt.savefig('example.svg', bbox_inches = 'tight', transparent=True)
```

The program runs and outputs a chart, but the font message is frustrating.

I read somewhere that MatPlotLib uses the font cache.  Check this out.  The font is present.  For good measure, I tried copying the font to another locations on my drive: `/usr/local/share/fonts`. I was careful to make the file perms the same as the parent (root).  Once I moved it, `fc-list` detected the fonts.

```
$ fc-list | grep -i Montserrat
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_100italic.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat Thin:style=Thin Italic,Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_900italic.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat Black:style=Black Italic,Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_200italic.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_700.ttf: Montserrat:style=Bold
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_500italic.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_800italic.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat ExtraBold:style=ExtraBold Italic,Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_italic.ttf: Montserrat:style=Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_100.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat Thin:style=Thin,Regular
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_600italic.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_regular.ttf: Montserrat:style=Regular
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_900.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat Black:style=Black,Regular
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_500.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_600.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_700italic.ttf: Montserrat:style=Bold Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_300.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat Light:style=Light,Regular
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_300italic.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_800.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat ExtraBold:style=ExtraBold,Regular
/home/myname/.local/share/fonts/Montserrat_200.ttf: Montserrat,Montserrat ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
```

I'm at a loss of what to do to fix this.

Where does MatPlotLib actually look for the fonts?

Comment: I encountered the same problem and couldn't solve it for half a day